# How to enable input type submit button

Tags: android, cordova

I have drop down list and input type submit button in my Android Phonegap application.
By default I disabled submit button and I would like to enable button onchange event of my drop down list.

I tried below options

```
$("buttonId").attr("disabled", false);

$("buttonId").removeAttr("disabled");
```

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/disable-enable-button-in-form

Written event listener based on above link

But above options didn't work for me. Could some one help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try Below code, for managing disable/enabling input button based on dropdown "dropList" 's change event. be make sure u did not added "disabled" property in HTML for input submit button "default_sub". and let assume that the page id is default.

put below code inside onDocumentReady event.

```
//PageShow event task binding
$('#default').on('pageshow', function(){
    //setup disabled property for submit button.
    $("#default_sub").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});

//Submit button click for test alert only
$('#default_sub').on("tap, click", function(){
    alert("Submit : Pressed");
});

//Dropdowns onChange Event binding  
$('#dropList').on('change',function(){
    //Removing Disabled property
    $("#default_sub").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

This code is working for me to enable button based on  Dropdown's onchange event.

the above code will be applicable for <'input type="submit"> tag only but will not make any effect on its UI, if u r using jquery data-role="button" along with div then u can disable and enable button using addClass/removing class 'ui-disabled' to its class attribute.

Thanks, 
Prashant Agrawal

Comment: I tried button click is disable but CSS of button is not changed

Comment: I replaced submit button with jquery data-role button and able to disable and enable button using addClass('ui-disabled')

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this.

```
document.getElementById('submitbuttonidhere').disabled = false;
```

You can also try this.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" disabled="disabled"/>
$("input[name='submit']").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: @rpelluru Be sure your onchange event call .

Comment: Yep, it's invoking properly and I added few console.log and it's printing without any issues